# How to see .NET inner exception in IronPython interactive window?

Tags: python, .net, exception, ironpython, read-eval-print-loop

```
IronPython 2.7.5 (2.7.5.0) on .NET 4.0.30319.42000 (32-bit)
>>> from System import Exception
>>> raise Exception("outer", Exception("inner"))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Exception: outer
>>>
```

How can I see the details of the inner exception when working in an interactive IronPython window like this?

I tried `-X:ShowClrExceptions` and `-X:PassExceptions` and these work when running ipy64.exe from the command line, but seem to have no effect in the Visual Studio Interactive window (even though I can see in Process Hacker that it runs ipy64.exe with those parameters).

Comment: Sounds like VS only pulls in what's written to stdout? Maybe there's a setting in VS to capture things written to stderr in the same window? Or maybe it's written to a different window all together?  Maybe there's a way to send all output from stdout and stderr to stdout?